# Collecting definitions of continuity.

Tags: general-topology, definition, continuity, big-list

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote topological spaces and consider a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$. I'm collecting possible definitions/characterizations of the statement "$f$ is continuous."

Here's two to get us started.

- (Preimages of Open Sets) $f$ is continuous iff for all open $B \subseteq Y$ it holds that $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$.
- (Direct Images of Open Neighbourhoods) $f$ is continuous iff for all $x \in X$ and all open $B \ni f(x)$, there exists open $A \ni x$ such that $f(A) \subseteq B$.

Bring 'em on!

Edit: Intuitively sensible definitions of continuity, which nevertheless fail, are also welcome (provide a counterexample).

Edit2: Does anyone know a way of characterising continuity in terms of boundary operators?

Comment: Preimages of closed sets.

Comment: Should this be community wiki & big list?

Comment: @RobertHaraway How do I community wikify it?

Comment: Maybe check Bourbaki.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/941/community-wiki-checkbox-disappeared

Comment: Perhaps my community wiki comment was therefore out of line.

Comment: @RobertHaraway hahaha oh yeah WAYYY out of line. (not).

Comment: @RobertHaraway I would go as far as to say it was abusive, and morally disgusting. ;)

Answer (score 6):

- Inverse images of closed sets are closed.
- $f [ \overline{A} ] \subseteq \overline{ f[A] }$ for all $A \subseteq X$.
- $\overline{f^{-1} [ B ] } \subseteq f^{-1} [ \overline{B} ]$ for all $B \subseteq Y$;
- $f^{-1} [ \mathrm{Int} (B) ] \subseteq \mathrm{Int} ( f^{-1} [ B ] )$ for all $B \subseteq Y$.
- whenever $\langle x_\sigma : \sigma \in \Sigma \rangle$ is a net in $X$ with limit $x$, then  $f(x)$ is a limit of the net $\langle f(x_\sigma) : \sigma \in \Sigma \rangle$ in $Y$.  (Note that for this I am *not* assuming that nets have unique limits.)

Comment: Does the fifth dot point require qualification? As in "If $X$ and/or $Y$ is Hausdorff, then whenever..."

Comment: Also, does the fourth dot point have a "direct images" version?

Comment: Hausdorff is not needed for the nets characterization. If a net has 2 limits, then their images (if different) are also limits of the image net.

Comment: @user18921: I'll clarify the fifth point, but in general I don't assume that nets have unique limits.  As for the fourth point, the natural candidate for a "direct image" version would be $f [ \mathrm{Int} ( A ) ] \subseteq \mathrm{Int} ( f [ A ] )$, which fails for constant functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: In my opinion the natural candidate for a "direct image" version would be $\mathrm{int}(f(A))\subseteq f(\mathrm{int}(A))$ which is to the second dot point as the third is to the fourth. However, this fails, too. Take $X=\mathbb R$, $Y=\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, $f(x)=x^2$, and $A=\mathbb R_{\ge0}$. Then $\mathrm{int}(f(A))=Y$ but $f(\mathrm{int}(A))=\mathbb R_{>0}$. For bijective functions, however, it is just the dual of (2).

Comment: @StefanH.  Upon further thought, I have to agree with your assessment on the "naturality" of the potential condition.  Nice example, too!

Comment: Thanks. I struggle to find an example for an injective but not surjective map. I don't know if bijectivity is really necessary or injectivity would suffice.

Comment: I gave it some thought, and for an injective continuous map $f:X\to Y$ the inclusion is valid. Let $A\subseteq X$ and $y\in\mathrm{int}(f(A))$. Then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in A$. The preimage of $\mathrm{int}(f(A))$ is an open subset of $A$ containing $x$. Hence $x$ is interior point of $A$ and $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Ok, finally I found a counter-example: Let $X=[0,2]$, $Y=[0,3]$, and $f:X\to Y$ maps $x$ to $x$ if $x<1$ and to $x+1$ if $x\ge1$. Clearly $f$ is not continuous, but it is injective and satisfies the inclusion $\mathrm{int}(f(A))\subseteq f(\mathrm{int}(A))$. After all, the inclusion can only characterize continuity if $f$ is bijective.

Answer (score 6):

For every net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ that converges to some $x$ in $X$, $f(x_i)_{i \in I}$ converges to $f(x)$.

For every filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ that converges to $x \in X$, $f[\mathcal{F}]$ converges to $f(x)$.

The inverse image of a closed set in $Y$ is closed in $X$.

For a fixed base $\mathcal{B}$ of $Y$, the inverse image of $O$ is open for every $O \in \mathcal{B}$.

As the previous statement, but then for subbases.

For every $A \subset X$, $f[\overline{A}] \subset \overline{f[A]}$

For every $B \subset Y$, $\overline{f^{-1}[B]} \subset f^{-1}[\overline{B}]$

For every $B \subset Y$, $f^{-1}[\operatorname{Int}(B)] \subset \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}[B])$